# Which English speech sounds are difficult for a learner from Jamaica to say? (I'm aware of /θ/)

Tags: pronunciation

On 11.1.21. I'm going to start working with a Jamaican learner of English to support her with her spoken and written English.

I understand that θ and ð may be difficult for her to say, but please can anyone identify any other sounds that may be challenging for her? I want to be well-prepared for our meeting so I can be as helpful to her as possible.

I believe she was brought up speaking Jamaican Patois.

Is she likely to find any particular aspects of English grammar difficult?

If anyone's able to throw any light on these questions, I'd be very grateful!